# PDO postgresql COPY

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, pdo

```
function exportToCsv () {

  $dbh = new PDO('pgsql:'
            . (env('DB_DATABASE') ? ';dbname='.env('DB_DATABASE') : '')
            . (env('DB_HOST') ? ';host='.env('DB_HOST') : '')
            , env('DB_USERNAME') 
            , env('DB_PASSWORD')
          );

  $dbh -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
  $sth = $dbh->prepare('COPY (select * from ?) TO \'/tmp/report.csv\' DELIMITER \',\' CSV HEADER;');
  $sth -> execute(['stats']);
};
```

i have error after execute this code

```
PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near &quot;$1&quot;
LINE 1: COPY (select * from $1) TO '/tmp/report.csv' DELIMITER ',' C...
```

i use laravel, and i try execute parameterized copy query.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. You cannot use `COPY` in a prepared statement with parameters.
2. You cannot use a parameter for an identifier like a table name.

You will have to write the table name into the `COPY` statement.

Comment: 1) WHY?
2) ok
I want execute complex query with many conditions inside COPY. Which is the best way for this? Laravel query builder and PDO not suitable for this case?

Comment: Ad "why": Because it rarely happens that anybody wants to execute the same `COPY` statement with different parameters, which is the main use case for prepared statements. Ad Laravel query builder: I don't know, can it be used to compose query strings? If yes, you could construct an SQL query and concatenate that with the rest of the ´COPY` command you need.